# How to get request.user to filter data in django forms?

Tags: django, filter

I have this code:

```
# forms.py
channels = Channel.objects.filter(company=user)
channel = forms.ChoiceField(
    choices=channels, 
    widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
)

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
    super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

def clean_channel(self):
    channel = self.cleaned_data.get('channel')
    if self.user:
        return channel
```

But `user` is not deffined.

How to get `request.user` to filter data in forms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got it in `__init__`, so you should do the filtering there.

```
channel = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    queryset=Channel.objects.all(), 
    widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
)

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
    super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['channel'].queryset = Channel.objects.filter(company=user)
```

Note, I've changed your field type to ModelChoiceField, which accepts a queryset argument.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to do something like this in your views

```
channel = forms.ModelChoiceField
    (queryset=Channel.objects.all(), 
    widget=forms.Select(attrs= {'class': 'form-control'}))
```

So instead of overidding `__init__`, you do something like this in your In `views.py`

```
form = ChannelForm()
form.fields['channel'].queryset = Channel.objects.filter(company=user)
```